# jQuery - if clause to run function if link has a specific ID

Tags: jquery

I need to run a script if a link clicked is `artist_link`. The reason I need to do this is because I have a history api script and the script needs to run if this link is clicked. It runs on page load but since the history api ajaxes in the content there is no page loads.

Here's what I have;

```
if ($('a').attr('id') == 'artist_link'){ alert ('hello'); }
```

Okay I should have explained this. It must be an if clause since the script will only be ran **IF** the link clicked has that specific ID. The clause is within an AJAX request which is part of my history api script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (responseData) {

        $("#main").hide().html($("#load", responseData)).fadeIn(500); //fadeIn new page
        if (url =='Home'){
         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "AJAX/request_feed.js",
         dataType: "script"
         });
        }
        if (url =='Discover'){

         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "AJAX/get_artists.js",
         dataType: "script"
         });

         }

         if ($('a').attr('id') === 'artist_link'){ alert ('hello'); }   
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location.replace("404");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, the click function is right at the start of the history script so I just need to determine if the `a` clicked has that specific ID

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to run a script if a link clicked is artist_link

And what's wrong with just targeting the ID and setting up a click function then ?

```
$("#artist_link").on('click', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
   //do ajax stuff here
   if (event.target.id=='artist_link') {
       //do some stuff if the right link was clicked ...
       //make sure you don't redefine the event, and it will be available in
       //the ajax functions scope as well (as long as it's inside the click function)
   }
});
```

Comment: Should have explained that really. The if clause must be within the ajax section of my history api script. I'll put this bit in the question

Comment: Works great thank! Had to make a few edits to it but that was only becuase I didn't provide you with information that I should have done

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding HTML elements dynamically after page load then use this

```
$(document).on('click', '#artist_link', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: This only applies if the link itself was added dynamically, which the question does'nt really say anything about, but I'll upvote it anyway, as it will work just the same!

Comment: Thanks! Added this just in case the OP finds it not working. Personally I bubble/delete events so that I don't have to worry about them not working later. Is that a good/bad practice?

Comment: @atif089 - It can be both good and bad practice? If you're attaching all your event handlers to the document just to make sure they work, I'd say it's bad practice. If you're attaching event handlers to parents when elements are removed/moved/inserted etc. I'd say it's good practice etc.